# Why is a ST_Union within same table slow - shouldn't it be instant?

Tags: postgis, performance

I'm working in Postgres 9.6. I have a table that looks like this:

```
 gid        | integer                     | not null default nextval('usgovt_gid_seq'::regclass)
 category   | character varying(12)       |
 geom       | geometry(MultiPolygon,5070) |
Indexes:
    "usgovt_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
    "ix_usgovt_category" btree (category)
    "usgovt_geom_idx" gist (geom)
```

I want to retrieve the union of every polygon with a category of 1:

```
SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom
FROM usgovt
WHERE category='1'
GROUP BY category;
```

However this query is EXTREMELY slow (half an hour and hasn't finished yet), and this is on a reasonably powerful machine, and I've tweaked Postgres's memory settings etc.

Why is this slow? Shouldn't it be instant? Since this is a single table, presumably the polygons can't overlap, so it's pretty much just an additive operation. PostGIS just needs to add them together to make a single large MultiPolygon.

Or perhaps polygons can overlap within a table? If so, is there some way to tell PostGIS that these polygons don't overlap, so it can just add them together?

Comment: Union removes overlapping areas and also common boundaries. It is not extremely light especially if geometries have lots of vertices.

Comment: Perhaps you do not want to make a union with internal boundaries removed but just a collection with http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html. What Union is for PostGIS and in OGC standards is Merge for ESRI which makes confusion sometimes.

Comment: Could you draw a sketch about what you have and what is your goal? I may understand you wrong.

Comment: Polygons can overlap within a table.

Comment: @user30184 the postgis st_union behaves more like the ESRI dissolve tool...

Comment: maybe run a self join...

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS has no way to know that the polygons have no overlaps, so it's performing the same expensive overlay calculations that it would need to do for a set of polygons with arbitrary overlaps and intersections.

It's possible to perform a much faster union using with the following approach, though it's difficult to implement well in SQL:

1. Extract all segments of all polygons
2. Remove duplicate segments
3. Polygonize the result
4. Remove polygons representing holes

Comment: Thanks. For my purposes I can skip 2 since I know there aren't any duplicates! How would I go about 1 and 3?

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate a minimal example about this. Or provide some hints on which functions to use in each step. Tks.